# Average time to find a duplicate with pairwise independence

Tags: probability

Assume a process that samples uniformly at random from the range $[1,\ldots,n]$. I am interested in the expected time to find a duplicate given only that the sampling process is pairwise independent. That is I would like to find the expected time until a sample matches one of the samples taken before.

One way to compute the expected time is
$$E=\sum_{x=1}^\infty P(X \geq x).$$  Here $X$ is a random variable that represents the time at which the first duplicate is found.

If the samples were fully independent then we would have that  $$\sum_{x=1}^\infty P(X \geq x) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty \prod_{i=1}^{x-1} (1-i/n).$$ 
We can bound this quantity using the fact that $e^{-2x} \leq 1-x \leq e^{-x}$ when $0 \leq x \leq 0.5$ and then bound the resulting sum using an integral. This gives an asymptotic bound of $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ steps.

How would you perform a similar analysis where we only have pairwise independence and also preferably get an asymptotic result rather than just an upper bound?

EDIT: Following Henry's great reply, I would really like to know a lower bound as well as the upper bound he has given.  In particular, does the lower bound for fully independent sampling of $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ also apply to this pairwise independent case?  Or alternatively, can anyone think of a pairwise independent process that has mean less than order $\sqrt{n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worst case is $O(n)$.  Clearly by pigeonhole arguments the expectation cannot exceed $n+1$ but there are examples where it exceeds $n$.

Suppose the samples are $S_1, S_2, \ldots$ and

- that $S_1$ has a uniform distribution on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$,
- that with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ you have $S_1 =  S_2 = \cdots = S_{n} $ and with probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$ you have $S_j$ having a uniform distribution on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\} - \{S_1,\ldots , S_{j-1} \}$  for $2 \le j \le n$ and
- that $S_{n+1}$ has a uniform distribution on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ independently of all the others,

then there is a probability $\frac{1}{n}$ that you need a sample size of $2$ and a   probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$ you need a sample size of $n+1$ to find a duplicate value.  This gives an expectation of $n+\frac{1}{n}$ which is $O(n)$.

Comment: That's great thanks.  I would really like to know a lower bound as well as this interesting upper bound you have given. I will edit the question to explain that as well.

Comment: If you have time, it might be worth adding a sentence on why the sampling process you describe is pairwise independent as I think this is a problem lots of people would be interested in.

Comment: What's your view on a lower bound?

Comment: @Arlo: I suspect the fully independent version may give the lower bound

Comment: Bounty awarded as this was the best answer received on math stackexchange.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple lower bound proof was given at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102079/bounds-for-duplicate-finding-with-limited-independence by Douglas Zare. I include a slightly edited copy for completeness.

The expected number of duplicates among the first $m$ is an upper bound for the probability of a duplicate in the first $m$. For $m=c\sqrt{n}$ the expected number of duplicates is under $c/2$, so the probability that the first duplicate is greater than $\sqrt{n}$ is greater than $1/2$, which means the expected first duplicate is greater than $\sqrt{n}/2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [generalized birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#The_generalized_birthday_problem).  Your $n$ is $d$ in the article.

Comment: The main difference is that my problem can only assume pairwise independence so those results don't seem to hold.  Also I want to know the expected number of samples to get a duplicate not the number needed to get probability at least 1/2 of getting a duplicate.

Comment: @Arlo: For your second point, try further down the [same page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people)

Comment: Good point, thanks.